# What is the difference between Zero Shot Learning and clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, clustering

I recently found out about ZSL and to me, it is very similar to a clustering algorithm with one difference: a clustering algorithm such as DBSCAN doesn't need to have a pre-defined group of feature vectors and we just give it the data but in ZSL we need to feed the data to a ZSL and then map and cluster the output feature vector with other feature vectors that we have from before.

Maybe I am wrong but what is the difference between ZSL and clustering and what are its advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clustering is unsupervised and as such does not use any labels.

Zero-shot learning is a form of learning which does not conform to standard supervised framework: the classes are not assumed to be known beforehand (you evaluate on unseen classes), but it does assume some relationships between classes (for example some methods assume encodings for classes, then you can think that's something like embeddings for classes, for example you use word embeddings for some words instead of one-hot encoded matrix).

The main advantage of this approach lies in the fact that it is able to leverage structure that exists on classes - this enables these methods to work where standard supervised learning methods fail - handling unseen/very small classes is a typical example.

Comment: Maybe I didn't get the ZSL correctly but how it leverages "structure that exists on classes"? I mean the next step after having a feature vector generated by a NNet is using a clustering algorithm such as k-nn to find its correct class. So why not use a feature selector + clustering algorithm instead?

Comment: If you checked out ZSL papers, you'd see that they use dense vectors to represent classes, like for example using word embeddings of category names. This contrasts to clustering which doesn't assume any structure on clusters. In other words, ZSL assumes vector labels, and clustering has categorical labels.

Comment: I would like to know, besides assumption about the difference in structure as you commented - what are the other differences between `unsupervised learning` and `zero-shot learning` then?. As I know they both seek for hidden patterns in samples and eventually `unsupervised learning` will lead to labeled samples.

Comment: "unsupervised learning will lead to labeled samples" - this is not true. For example dimensionality reduction doesn't have to produce anything that looks like labels.